# How to add before_widget 2 div

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, codex, wordpress-4.3

[image]

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Main Widget Area', 'predator' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Appears in the footer section of the site.', 'predator' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="col-md-3"><div id="%1$s" class="footer-widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4>',
        'after_title'   => '<span class="head-line"></span></h4>',
    ) );
```

before_widget how to add 2 div? now combine all div in one div.

Or
another way like sidebar first widget before add col-md-6 and others col-md-3

Comment: I think that those classes are handled by wordpress.

Comment: yes but any other method filter or action for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you can apply div whereever you want,just apply this script in your wp footer, i hope it will help you.

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".widget-1").append("");

    $(".widget-1").append("");

})